# Value of $\int_{\partial B(w,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$ using Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Using Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem for a multiply connected domain, answer the following question:
Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in a domain $\Omega$, and $\overline{B}(w,R)\subset \Omega$, where $\overline{B}(w,R)$ is the closure of $B(w,R)$, explain why
$$\int_{\partial B(w,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz = \int_{\partial B(w,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$$
whenever $0<r<R$.
Explain what this implies about the right-hand integral.

I'm not sure how the theorem will be used here, I just thought that if $f$ is holomorphic over this domain, then all contours can be deformed, but I don't think they're necessarily equal...
I have a feeling the right hand integral is zero since that's a result of the theorem.

The theorem for multiply connected domain is:
**Cauchy Goursat's Theorem.** Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain whose $\partial \Omega$ consists of finitely many disjoint contours. Let $\Gamma_0$ say be the contour outside $\Omega$ while the others $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\ldots,\Gamma_n$ are inside $\Omega$. Suppose also $f\in H(\Upsilon)$, where $\overline{\Omega} \subset \Upsilon$. Then

$$\int_{\partial\Omega}f(z)dz = \sum_{j=0}^n\int_{\partial \Gamma_j}f(z)dz = 0.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D = B(w,R) \setminus B(w,r)$. Then $\dfrac{f(z)}{z-w}$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of $D$ (since $D \subset \Omega$, and $w \notin D$). Hence by Cauchy's integral theorem (Cauchy-Goursat in your terminology),
$$
0 = \int_{\partial D} \dfrac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz =  \int_{\partial B(w,R)} \dfrac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz - \int_{\partial B(w,r)} \dfrac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz.
$$
The minus sign comes from the fact that the inner boundary of $D$ must be oriented clockwise. (The integral over $\partial D$ should be taken with positive orientation, i.e. $\partial B(w,R)$ counterclockwise and $\partial B(w,r)$ clockwise.)

Comment: That makes sense!  
What would this say about the right hand side value though?  
I just think that it'd say that it is independent of $R$ but I'm unsure.

Comment: Since for all $0<r<R$ we have $\int_{\partial B(w,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz=\int_{\partial B(w,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$, we can take the limit $r\rightarrow 0$ and get:

Comment: $2\pi if(w)=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\int_{\partial B(w,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz=\int_{\partial B(w,R)}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$ since the right-hand side is independent of $r$.