# $\int_{\partial B_4(1)}\frac{2e^{iz}}{z^2(z-\pi)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

My task is to calculate the following integral $$\int_{\partial B_4(1)}\frac{2e^{iz}}{z^2(z-\pi)}dz.$$
Therefore I should use the follwoing theorem:

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be an open set and $f:U\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic.
Let $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ be two homologous cycles in $U$. Then $\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\Gamma_2}f(z)dz.$

So far I have failed to prove holomorphy of $f$. Because $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2$ should be two homologous cycles in $U$, it follows $\partial B_4(1)\subset U$. But because of $z^2(z-\pi)=0$ for $z=0,\pi$ and $0,\pi\in B_4(1)$, I dont know how to show it...
Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the $f$ in your post? You are looking at the wrong theorem if you set $f(z)=\frac{2e^{iz}}{z^2(z-\pi)}$. Try the residue theorem.

Comment: @user1046533 Unfortunately, I don't know the residue theorem yet. I chose f as you suspected in order to be able to apply the theorem above.

Comment: What book are you using? You can also apply Cauchy's theorem with another choice of $f$. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2452328

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $z=0,z=\pi$ are two pole of $f=\frac{2e^{iz}}{z^2(z-\pi)}$ in $\mathbb{B}_4(1)$, then
$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}_4(1)}f(z)\,d z=\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}_{0.5}(0)}f(z)\,d z+\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}_{0.5}(\pi)}f(z)\,d z\\
=2\pi i\bigg[\text{R}(f,z=0)+\text{R}(f,z=\pi)\bigg].
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but why is it allowed to split up the integral like this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: observe that the paths $\partial \mathbb{B}(1,4)$ and $\partial \mathbb{B}(z_0,r)$, for any chosen $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$ large enough, are homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,\pi\}$, therefore

$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}(1,4)}f(z)\,d z=\int_{\partial \mathbb{B}(z_0,r)}f(z)\,d z
$$

for $f(z):=\frac{2e^{iz}}{z^2(z-\pi)}$. By last, if you separate the integrand in simple fractions, that is if you find $a,b,c\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\frac1{z^2(z-\pi)}=\frac{a}{z^2}+\frac{b}{z}+\frac{c}{z-\pi}$ then the integral becomes the sum of three very simple integrals.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! Unfortunately, the concept of homotopy has not yet been introduced, and it is not allowed to use partial fraction, only the theorem